# Chrome extension "all_frames" is invalid

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

### Question

I tried to make a plugin to help modify the `navigator.platform`, in the main page(the web browser requested page) is well, but I found that if there is a `iframe` in the page, `iframe` in the page will not be modified by my `content_scripts.js`, although I have to set up in the `manifest.json` file all_frames: true`. This is why?

### manifest.json

```
{  
    "name": "Platform Modifier",  
    "version": "1.0.0.0",  
    "manifest_version":2,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
    "background":{
        "persistent":true,
        "scripts":["bg.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
        "default_title": "Platform Modifier",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["content_scripts.js"],
        "run_at":"document_start"
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
        "insert-script.js"
    ]
}
```

### content_scripts.js

```
var xmlhttp = null;
var url = chrome.extension.getURL("insert-script.js");

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

if(xmlhttp == null){
    console.log("not support XMLHTTP")
}else{
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function state_Change(){
    if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({op: "getAll"}, function(response) {
            var replaceList = {
                "TAG_PlatForm":response.value.platform,
                "TAG_UserAgent":response.value.userAgent
            };
            var sc=document.createElement("script");
            sc.type="text/javascript";
            sc.innerHTML= replaceText(xmlhttp.responseText,replaceList);
            var html=document.getElementsByTagName("html");
            html[0].appendChild(sc);
        });
    }
}

function replaceText(str,regexp){
    for(var key in regexp){
        str = str.replace(key,regexp[key]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

### insert-script.js

```
var myPlatForm = function() {
        return 'TAG_PlatForm';
};
var myUserAgent = function() {
    return 'TAG_UserAgent';
};
if (Object.defineProperty) {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'platform', {
        get: myPlatForm
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
        get: myUserAgent
    }); 
} else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('platform', myPlatForm);
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', myPlatForm);
}
```

### Complete file

[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdoenejj2rzr2ko/package.zip?dl=0), this file contains two parts: `extensions.zip` is the Chrome extension; `testPages.zip` is the HTML file for testing. In the test file, open the `main.html`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the problem.

Comment: Thanks again, I have uploaded the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value **is** changed, just later than it is displayed in `<body onload`, you can check it in devtools:

[image: screenshot]

The errors in the console are fixed by using the correct condition in XHR (the code was injected multiple times for each XHR loading stage, the copies tried to redefine a non-configurable property):

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
```

As for reducing the delay:

- Currently you're waiting for XHR to fetch the injected script and waiting for the message request to the background page.
- Instead put the injected script code as a literal string in your content script and use `chrome.storage.local` and access the values directly in the content script and the popup page.